# Could an Ingress be attached to a Loadbalancer type service in GKE?

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine

I already have a `Loadbalancer` service for my a `Deployment`. I now want to add an `Ingress` on top of the service. Would I need to change the type of service to `NodePort`?

Current service

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: name-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: name
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9000 #this service is reachable at this port
      targetPort: 9000 #this service will forward the request to correspoding nodes of the service at this port
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I want to add this `Ingress`

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: name-https-loadbalancer-ingress
  annotations:
    # If the class annotation is not specified it defaults to "gce".
    #There are two Ingress classes available for GKE Ingress. The gce class deploys an external load balancer and the gce-internal class deploys an internal load balancer. Ingress resources without a class specified default to gce.
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: SomeReservedIP
    networking.gke.io/managed-certificates: SomeSSLCertificate
spec:
  rules:
    - http:
        paths:
          - path: /*
            backend:
              serviceName: name-service
              servicePort: 9000
```

The examples on `GCP` website use `Nodeport`.

As I already have a `Loadbalancer` service and `Ingress` also creates a `Loadbalancer`, I am wondering if this causes issues

Answer (score 1):

Since on k8s, kind: Service and kind: Ingress are different things, here is a little summary about each one:

As per [Service](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/), is a An abstract way to expose an application running on a set of Pods as a network service. Meanwhile [Ingress](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/), exposes HTTP and HTTPS routes from outside the cluster to services within the cluster. Traffic routing is controlled by rules defined on the Ingress resource.

Also, there are a defined ports that you are able to use for an HTTP(s), and node port, for example, for an HTTP(s) you can only use ports 80, 443 and 8080.

So, the answer is yes, if you have an ingress and a service with the same port, this is causing an issue. My recommendation is to review [this](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/tutorials/http-balancer) guidance about to configure an ingress on a HTTP(s) LB.

I hope this information will be helpful to you.